# creating cron job that sends output to file every day and overwrites this file every month

Tags: linux, cron

I need help with cron job that sends output to file every day and overwrites this file every month my only problem is how to make it overwrite each month and I need this in one job so creating 2 jobs one that outputs to a file and other removing it every month is out of picture

Comment: may I ask why writing 2 jobs is out of picture?

Comment: Can you please add a little more detail about what's going on, so there will be better answers.  Is this a daily backup, but then the last backup of each month is preserved (or suchlike)?

Comment: its about log file for obvious reason i want to prevent it from filling up my whole drive by rewriting it every month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run it every day but use `date +%w` to print the day number and act differently (call with `>` to clobber the file instead of `>>` to append) based on that.

Note that some cron daemons require `%` to be escaped, hence `\%`.

```
# Run every day at 00:30 but overwrite file on Mondays; append every other day.
# Note that this requires bash as your shell.
# May need to override with SHELL=/bin/bash
30 00 * * * if [ "$(date +\%w)" = "1" ]; then /your/command > /your/logfile; else /your/command >> /your/logfile; fi
```

**Edit:**

You mention in comments above that your actual goal is log rotation.

The norm for Linux systems is to use something like `logrotate` to manage logs like this. That also has the advantage that you can keep multiple previous log files and compress them if you like.

I would recommend making use of a logrotate config snippet to accomplish your goal instead of doing it in the cron job itself. To put this in the cron job is counter-intuitive if it's merely for log rotation.

Here's an example logrotate snippet, which may go in a location like `/etc/logrotate.d/yourapp` depending on which Linux distribution you're using.

```
/var/log/yourlog {
    daily
    missingok
    # keep one year of logs
    rotate 365
    compress
    # keep the first one uncompressed for ease of viewing
    delaycompress
}
```

This will result in your log file being rotated daily, with the first iteration being like `/var/log/yourlog.1` and then compressed iterations like `/var/log/yourlog.2.gz`, `/var/log/yourlog.3.gz` and so on.

In my opinion therefore, your question is not actually a cron question. The kind of cron trickery used above would only be appropriate in situations such as when you want a job to fire on the last Sunday of the month, or the last day of the month, or other criteria that can't be expressed in cron syntax.